# How to decide on type in template argument (i.e. ternary operator at compile time)?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, class-template

I want some easy, light solution to such syntaxis:

```
template <bool is_true>
class A {
    B<is_true ? int : float> var;  // B is just some other templated class
};
```

And I **do not** want something of that kind (though, it looks normal, I just want everything to look needed and not to create single-time structures and declare their specializations):

```
template <bool>
struct HelperClass {
    using type = void;
};

template <>
struct HelperClass<true> {
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct HelperClass<false> {
    using type = float;
};

// 'HelperClass<is_true>::type' instead of ternary operator
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiomatic solution is using [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```cpp
template <bool is_true>
class A {
    B<std::conditional_t<is_true, int, float>> var;
};
```

Comment: Accepted (need 9 mins to wait)